# maven assembly:single doesn't resolve dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I am trying to make a single jar with all dependencies resolved so that I can run this jar from command prompt. I am using maven's `assembly:single` but whenever I am doing so, I get an issue

```
[ERROR] com.XXX.XXXX.XXX:XXX-XXX-XXX:jar:XXX
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] A (http://XXXXX/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] B (http://XXXX/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] C (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/, releases=true, snapshots=true
),
[ERROR] D (https://XXXXX, releases=false, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) com.test.Report:myjar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

This is the pom I am working with 
Now these jars are already resolved and are present in Maven Dependency folder. I can run the whole project from Eclipse but need to give this jar to client with all the jars included. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Calling from command that way there is not dependency resolution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Probably no one would be looking at this answer but still I would like to have a note for my future self. This issue was different from what exception I was getting. To run any `plugin` make sure that `<plugin>` is inside `<plugins>` inside `<build>` (not under `<pluginManagement>`). Doing this ran the plugin and jar with dependencies was formed upon `mvn install`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the "jar-with-dependencies" configuration in your pom.xml. This will package all your dependencies in the jar.
For eg:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- any other plugins -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Another approach is to use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html).
For eg:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The maven shade plugin will basically create two jars at the end. The first jar is the normal jar which contains just the compiled classes of your source code.
The second jar will also contain your compiled classes **but** it will also include the class files from all your dependencies. This is the jar that you should give to your client.